# JVM settings best practices for running app by "java -jar"

Tags: java, jvm

I have jar with my spring boot application. 
I want to pass some arguments related to heap size etc. Using it in command line is the only option?
 
I tried to create .conf file or use it in pom.xml with  but that does not works.
I'm starting the apllication using java - jar

Comment: Create a batch file or a shell script or both and use that to start your app. That would be my suggestion anyway.

Comment: Hm, or maybe dockerfile even. thanks